# Redirect Browser to Landing Page in Apple App Store application

Tags: macos, cocoa, redirect, proxy, app-store

I am trying to build a simple web filter, which should be a easy task.

However, this filter must conform to Apple's App Store guidelines.

The App Store guidelines specify that an app cannot leave its sandbox.

That means that I cannot edit `/etc/hosts`. Configuring the system proxy and DNS settings requires root privileges, so running a proxy and pointing to it won't work. I cannot distribute a non-sandboxed, privileged daemon within an App Store app.

I'm left scratching my head. I have found apps that are either on the App Store or they don't require elevated privileges to operate.

Some examples are:

1) [1Focus](http://onefocusapp.com/) -> Redirects browsers to a landing page when trying to go to blocked websites. Interestingly enough, this redirection only happens on certain web browsers. `curl` et al. can pull the blocked site.

2) [Focus](https://heyfocus.com/) -> Again, redirects web browsers. Doesn't require root privileges

From my research, it seems like using `NEFilterDataProvider` from the Network Extension framework could work for this purpose. However, the documentation states that browsers cannot be redirected to arbitrary sites, only that they can be told to redirect to macOS/iOS's "blocked website" page.

Again, the above apps are in the app store and are able to redirect browsers to custom landing pages based on a given domain name.

Does anyone have any insight towards what I can do?

Thanks